# Discord.py: Changing Nickname if user has specific role

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to make my bot change someone's Nickname, if this user Has a specific role, so pretty much a Role Prefix system. So i tried it like this, but it keeps giving me the error "Missing Permissions". Here's my Code:

```
@client.event
@has_role("Admin")
async def on_member_update(nick, member):
    await member.edit(nick="Admin | ")
```

Comment: Can you post the whole traceback?

Comment: It is the whole code, everything else are other events, commands and imports

Comment: Im asking for the error, not the code

Comment: discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions

Comment: The bot simply doesn't have permissions to edit the member, it's too low on the hierarchy or the member it's the owner of the server. Also note that the `has_role` decorator only works on commands, it will not work on events

Comment: So how to check if the user has a role?

Comment: simple if statement or create your own decorator

Comment: So like this: If member.role == "Admin" await member.edit("Admin | ")?

Comment: no, I can answer that question but it’s off-topic to the original question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229029/discussion-between-m4ximpl4yz-and-lukasz-kwiecinski).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bot simply doesn't have permissions to edit the member, it's too low on the hierarchy or the member it's the owner of the server. Also note that the `has_role` decorator only works on commands, it will not work on events

To make it work you should either use an if-statement or create your own decorator

- if-statement

```py
@client.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    role = discord.utils.get(before.guild.roles, name="Admin")
    if after in role.members:
        # Change the nick
```

- custom decorator

```py
from functools import wraps

def has_admin_role(coro):
    @wraps(coro)
    async def wrapper(before, after):
        role = discord.utils.get(before.guild.roles, name="Admin")
        if after in role.members:
            await coro(before, after)
    return wrapper


@client.event
@has_admin_role # Without calling it, it's hardcoded
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    # Edit the nick
```

Also note that the `has_admin_role` decorator will only work on the `on_member_update` event.

Comment: It says "discord.utils has no attribute get_roles"